# Show div above fixed navbar and let it scroll away

Tags: html, css

On my website www.aerycs.com I am trying to get a TrustBadge to show above the fixed navbar in responsive view (Smartphone).

My navbar is fixed on top and keeps staying there when the page is scrolled down.

The trustbadge is behind this element but won't show. If I just set the position to relative the entire area will scroll down which I want to avoid.

I can only use custom CSS since the HTML structure is given and can't be changed right now.

I've tried to play around with z-index which hasn't worked so far.

Trustbadge:
`<div id="trustbadgeXXX"></div>`

CSS:

```
#trustbadgeXXX {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background: none no-repeat scroll 0 transparent;
    font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    display: inline-block!important;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    clear: both;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Fixed Header:
`<header id="page-header" class="top-bar fixed-top">`

CSS:

````
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;

.top-bar {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;```
````

Comment: Hi. After visting your site, It seems that neither the div with id you mentioned nor the css with id, both not found.

Comment: Hi, the div id is a little different actually. It's tsbadgeResponsiveTop_db8d3657bdbe440c985ae127463eaad4

Comment: I would recommend that you may not stick (fix) the header in the start. If you need a trustbadge above the header, than you may need to use window.onscroll. Check the offset of the header with the window offset, and apply css to header to stick. So, basically you need to apply some script.

Comment: An example is given here : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried this:

added this script:
`<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("page-header");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>
`

added the sticky class:

`.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}`

Comment: Did you checked and changed header styles like in the example ?

Comment: I suppose you are making all changes on local first. So, we cant see exactly what changes have been done. Please also confirm which browser are you using for test ?

Comment: I have changed it in the live version already. You should see it in the sourcecode. I'm using chrome

Comment: But the trustbadge element is not there in the sourcecode. Is it dynamically added at runtime ?

Comment: It's added thorugh a script, you can search for `//widgets.trustedshops.com/js/XFC3851365E2D4354C08237FBFB11967A.js`

Comment: I think, the script that I mentioned has been removed now. badge is coming fine now. But as you mentioned it is giving issue in iPhone only. Which browser is used there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding below css to your badge may solve your problem (`z-index: 1031` so it will be above your header).

```
position: fixed; 
top: 0;
z-index: 1031;
```

In case you want it to scroll away, you can use `position: absolute` instead.

If you don't want the badge to overlay the header, you can use `position: sticky` for your header..

Comment: I did both of your suggestions and now the badge overlays the navbar element.You can see what I mean here: https://imgur.com/a/C8m9r5K

Comment: In your case, you can try removing `margin-top` of `#vue-app`, remove `overflow-x: hidden` of `.wrapper-main` and then add `position: sticky` to your header. Hope it help.

Comment: I think removing `overflow-x: hidden` is not an option since It will make the site scrollable on the horizontal axis. 
Could you check the current state of the site? When I narrow the window on my PC the badge shows up and scrolls away with the header. However, on an iPhone X it doesn't even show the badge

Comment: without removing `overflow-x: hidden`, `position: sticky` will not work. You can find information about this in google.

Comment: I am aware. Do you happen to know how to solve it otherwise? We don't want to remove `overflow-x:hidden`

Comment: Instead of putting `overflow-x: hidden` in `.wrapper-main`, you can put in its children `#page-body` and `.footer container-max`. May be it will help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196693/discussion-between-margsenjo-and-cuong-le-ngoc).

Comment: adding 
`.fixed-top { 
position: sticky!important; 
}
this will be:
.fixed-top { 
position: sticky!important; 
position: -webkit-sticky!important; 
}` did the job :)